# JavaScript treeview for large static website

Tags: javascript, tree, treeview

Need suggestion for a "treeview" (navigation) JS widget for a site that is:

1. Really large (up to 100,000 pages)
2. Static - all pages are generated from a external source, and the widget is embedded in every page.

To clarify: there are no frames, and no application server. All pages are generated and placed in a file system, each page is loaded independently, that means the treeview navigation will be loaded every time as well, so it should either use multiple files and load parts of the tree on demand, or to be super-efficient.

Commercial OK.

Answer (score 0):

All serious JS tree widgets allow dynamic loading of children. The key issue here is that most of them will send the server a query like `getChildren?parent=23674` and this won't do for your case.

Since the site is static, you need to generate files with descriptions of the branches of the tree in JSON format and request those from the server as the user expands nodes in the tree. You could also create files which contain the tree children as HTML but you will be more flexible when you send data to the client and use JavaScript to convert the data into HTML (plus you will save a lot of bandwidth).

Try Yahoo's [TreeView](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/). There is an [example how to load data dynamically](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/#dynamicloading).

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that none of the links are working. However there was one written for the exact same reason, which is efficiency on large number of data. You might want to check out [PixoTree](https://pixotree.pixobit.eu), and see if it's the right tool for you.

PS. I know it's an old question, but thought it might help someone who stumbles upon this question.